# Xcode project takes 10 minutes to build. Seems to get stuck on libtool?

Tags: xcode, performance, compilation, cocoapods, libtool-xcode

I'm looking at my build messages and it seems to get stuck here for a long time. This has only happened recently and very suddenly. I've tried to revert to previous revisions to no avail.

[image]

Libtool /Users/vu1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ThatInbox-astseeahhgcuwhgerbsnyfttztht/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a normal i386

It gets stuck at the above line for about 8-10 minutes sometimes with a clean build. 5 minutes or so with a previously successful build.

I've tried cleaning, deleting the derived data, trimming all cocoapods libraries with no success. I've also tried deleting the xcode project in the package folder and allowing it to reindex. It takes about 5-10 minutes to build even coming off of a successful build. In the past, it may have only taken 10-15 seconds at most.

Any ideas on where I should begin looking?